# State server logs Event ID 1078 The state server has closed an expired TCP/IP connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, event-log, iis-8.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Web Garden and State Server mode. I have noticed that in some occasion it throws below error:

> The state server has closed an expired TCP/IP connection. The IP
> address of the client is 127.0.0.1. The expired Read operation began
> at dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.

I have googled and found below [troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/state-server-event-1072-1076#symptoms) that applies to events ID 1072 and 1076,but mine is event ID 1078, so my question is: Is this solution valid for event ID 1078 as well (the error message is the same despite of event ID is different)?

Answer (score 1):

for event id 1072, 1076 and 1078 the below solution apply:

set below cod in web.conifg file:

```
<sessionState
stateNetworkTimeout="10" />
```

modify registry setting for TCP/IP operation time-out value for the state server:

1)Before modifying the registry value need to stop the service. open services and select ASP.NET state server service. right-click on the service and select stop.

[image]

2)open regedit(registry editor) from the start menu.

3)Locate the following key in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameter
```

4)Add a DWORD value that is named SocketTimeout. Set a positive integer to represent the new TCP/IP timeout in seconds.

After modifying the registry value restart the server and then start ASP.NET state server service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/state-server-event-1072-1076

Comment: I have already done this. I have increased both timeouts (web.config and registry key) to 45 seconds and this error continues appearing in the event log and consequently affecting to all clients connected to my ASP.NET MVC application (it stops working for a moment).

Comment: @Ralph may I know what is your application pool ideal time out value and recycling setting? did set this time out setting on all the state server? make sure you restart the server after doing the registry setting.

Comment: Jalpa, application pool recycling is disabled, time is set to 0. Regarding application pool ideal time out I do not understand you. And yes, I have set this time out in all the state servers (I only have one, and it is running in the same server/machine). Finally, no, I didn't restart the server after doing the registry change, is it necessary? I thought the change in the registry setting would be taken into account immediately without the need of restart the server.

Comment: Jalpa, I forgot to tell you in the previous comment: After change in the registry I restarted the ASP.NET State Service but the server was not restarted.

Comment: @Ralph after every registry changes we need to restart the machine